# Any Blogging software using Amazon SimpleDB?

Tags: blogs, amazon-simpledb

Is there any Blogging software (preferably .Net based) that uses Amazon SimpleDB for persistence?

Comment: Not programming related. Maybe serverfault.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any publicly available blogging software that uses SimpleDB.

Comment: I guess with the advent of Amazon RDS, one can use WordPress or BlogEngine.Net or for that matter any blogging application that uses a standard RDBMS and configure it to use MySQL (RDS) and make it work on Amazon.